# Moving subversion repositories

Tags: svn

Hello
 I have the following repositories:

```
/var/svn-repos/
              /project-repo1/
              /project-repo2/
              /project-repo3/
```

I would like to change this to:

```
/var/svn-repos/new-super-repo/
                             /project-folder1/
                             /project-folder2/
                             /project-folder3/
```

where project-repos1..3 are separate repositories and project-directory1..3 are directories of the "new-super-repo" repository.
Is this possible?
Will the history from the previous repositories be lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can dump the repositories with `svnadmin dump` and then use the `--parent-dir` option of `svnadmin load` to join them together into a new repository.

Note that this is a one-way process and that you will loose your current revision numbering.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new repo `new-super-repo`, and then use [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) to reference the other projects (repos) within it. History will be maintained.

Then, when a user checks out `new-super-repo`, they will also be checking out all the sub-repositories underneath it.

Note that when committing back, you will have to commit at the sub-repository level. Committing at the top-level will not automatically commit all the repos underneath.

Answer (score 2):

you can try out svn switch --relocate FROMPATH TOPATH

I guess this may help you.